# Scrapy using loops in Python

Tags: python, string, list, loops, scrapy

I want an activity to scrapy a web page. The part of data web is `route_data`.

```
route_data = ["javascript:mostrarFotografiaHemiciclo( '/wc/htdocs/web/img/diputados/peq/215_14.jpg', '/wc/htdocs/web', 'Batet Lamaña, Meritxell (Presidenta del Congreso de los Diputados)', 'Diputada por Barcelona', 'G.P. Socialista' ,'','');",
 "javascript:mostrarFotografiaHemiciclo( '/wc/htdocs/web/img/diputados/peq/168_14.jpg', '/wc/htdocs/web', 'Rodríguez Gómez de Celis, Alfonso (Vicepresidente Primero)', 'Diputado por Sevilla', 'G.P. Socialista' ,'','');",]
```

I create a dictionary with empty values.

```
dictionary_data = {"Nombre":None, "Territorio":None, "Partido":None, "url":None}
```

I have to save in `dictionary_data` each one line:

```
url = /wc/htdocs/web/img/diputados/peq/215_14.jpg

Nombre = Batet Lamaña, Meritxell
Territorio = Diputada por Barcelona
Partido = G.P. Socialista
```

For thus, and I loop over `route_data`.

```
for i in route_data:
    text = i.split(",")
    nombre = text[2:4]
    territorio = text[4]
    partido = text[5]
```

But the output is:

```
[" 'Batet Lamaña", " Meritxell (Presidenta del Congreso de los Diputados)'"]  'Diputada por Barcelona'  'G.P. Socialista' 
[" 'Rodríguez Gómez de Celis", " Alfonso (Vicepresidente Primero)'"]  'Diputado por Sevilla'  'G.P. Socialista'
```

How can it get put correct in dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
all_routes = []
for i in route_data:
    text = re.findall("'.+?'", i)
    all_routes.append(
    {"Nombre": re.sub('\(.*?\)', '', text[2]).strip(),
    "Territorio": text[3],
    "Partido": text[-2],
    "Url": text[0]})
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it is perfect!!